# How to push a DNS server for a specific domain?

Tags: openvpn

I have a domain (`example.com`) which is setup to have two views. `host1.example.com` will be `10.0.0.1` in an internal network and `149.120.10.14` (a public IP) when queried from outside.

This means that a device connected to Internet should have its usual set of DNSes used normally (the ones it gets from DHCP, say `8.8.8.8`) and they will resolve `host1.example.com` to its external IP.

When connected via VPN, this device should however receive from the OpenVPN server a specific DNS to resolve `example.com` **(and only `example.com`)**.

My understading is that using

```
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.10.10.100"
```

where `10.10.10.100` is the internal, VPN reachable DNS server would overwrite the DNS servers on the device, loosing the ones it already had.

**Is there a way to push a DNS nameserver with the option to use it only for a specific domain and retain the existing other DNSes (used for Internet/company resolution)?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. But here is a workaround.

Setup a DNS server inside your VPN network and use it as DNS server for all VPN users.

On this DNS server, setup primary zone for your specific domain name (example.com) with the internal IP addresses. And setup DNS redirection to run DNS queries which the DNS server can't handle itself.

In this case, all DNS queries on the zone example.com will use DNS records from your server and all other DNS queries will be solved by 8.8.8.8 for example.

Comment: This is what I have today. The problem is that when I am in a place A, I get via DHCP the DNSes allowing me to resolve A's internal network and Internet. With your solution, i would get the DNS of the VPN network (place B) which resolves B's internal networks and Internet. I lose the ability to resolve A's names. Thus my quest for a domain-specific resolution in the VPN-provided DNS (keeping the local (A)  DNSes as well)

Comment: Setup A's zone (secondary DNS) on B's DNS server.

Comment: OK, now that I actually understood (yes, it took me time :)) what you mean - this is a very good solution. I set a forwarding of zone A (to its DNS servers) on the DNS I want to query and it works great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible, as the DNS resolving itself is done by the Client OS (just to be configured dynamically by OpenVPN), and all widely-used Client OS wouldn't be able to do different name resolution on a per-domain basis.